# UIRefreshControl use in iOS6 but not in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit

I want to add a UIRefreshControl for iOS6 users and a button for iOS5 users. I only want to have one package I deliver to the app store (obviously) so how can I do this?

I can sense the OS version

```
float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (ver >= 6.0) {
    // Programmatically add UIRefreshControl.
}
```

But if I want to support iOS5, the compiler won't let me use the UIRefreshControl?

Answer (score 8):

If the compiler don't let you use it, then let you fool him. You can (and **should**) also switch from OS version detection to feature detection. All in all:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIRefreshControl") != Nil) {
    id control = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIRefreshControl") alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: I'll add that Apple provides the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i). This shows the proper way to use runtime checks to look for frameworks, classes, and methods. It's very rare that code needs to check the `systemVersion`.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm too lazy to open it so I just ask you if this is the good ol' "mess with your base SDK and use weak linking" method? (if so, then that's also a good solution).

Comment: @rmaddy And where am I checking `systemVersion`?

Comment: Actually, just doing `id control = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIRefreshControl") alloc] init];` is safe because method calls on nil return nil. I've also rarely had problems simply doing things like `[UIRefreshControl class]`, which generally Just Works provided the SDK has the correct symbol visibility.

Comment: @tc. This is not actual production code, you know :) Of course it would return `nil` or non-`nil`, I just wanted to indicate that it's possible to branch based on the existence of a class. And yes, weak linking is even less painful (in case one considers an `if` with 3 lines of code to be painful).

Comment: @H2CO3 You're not using `systemVersion`, the OP is. I was making a general statement, adding support to your answer.